# How to make one <td> span both columns in a two column table?

Tags: html, css

[image: click to see the image]

How can I create a table like the above example in HTML and CSS.
I've tried the following:

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td style="width:50%">TEXT</td>
    <td style="width:50%">TEXT</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td style="width:100%">TEXT</td> 
  </tr>
```

but it won't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You should use `colspan` for your second row. Like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%">TEXT</td>
        <td style="width:50%">TEXT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="width:100%">TEXT</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

For learn -> [HTML Colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Answer (score 12):

[`<td>`s have a `colspan` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-colspan) that determine how many columns it should span over. You example has 2 columns to span, so your cleaned up code would look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"></td>
        <td width="50%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"></td>
        <td width="50%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- The important part is here -->
        <td colspan="2">This will have 100% width by default</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"></td>
        <td width="50%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"></td>
        <td width="50%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but the top section is wrong.  Most browsers will auto-size the columns based on the content, so you cannot guarantee that both columns will be equal width.

Comment: @Martin Right. I think I was going off that empty table cells would behave like that. I've made my answer more clear.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Cell 3 (Two columns)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

colspan will help you. [Link to more info.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)