# Content of cell should take all row without changing columns width

Tags: html, css

I want to have a little not standard table. This is how it should look:

[image]

This is my [demo](http://jsbin.com/kegogabine/edit?html,output). As you can see there, width of the first column is increased by text, but I don't want this behaviour. I want text to go from left to right in full row.

UPDATE:
For those who want to close question. Read below please.

I can't use additional `tr` and `td` with `colspan` for note. I use angular2 and datatables.net for tables and it will break selection and getting selected data.

Comment: what if you give a 'max-width' to your 'td' tag?

Comment: do you want to force content to be in the td and dont want to increase the width? or want that text to go from left to right in full row?

Comment: @SanjeevK I want text to go from left to right in full row, but without additional `tr` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make one <td> span both columns in a two column table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605976/how-to-make-one-td-span-both-columns-in-a-two-column-table)

Comment: @Xufox read update please

Comment: @user348173 Specify crucial restrictions like these immediately, please.

Comment: @Xufox I added restrictions. I can't use additional tr and td with colspan for note. I use angular2 and datatables.net for tables and it will break selection and getting selected data.

Comment: @user348173 I know. That’s what it already says in your question. I’m just saying that you should’ve told us about those restrictions a bit sooner.

Comment: @Xufox Yes, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use colspan

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Mark
            <div>Age: 18</div>
            <div>Income: 85</div>
             
        </td>
         <td>Otto</td>
         <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="3"><div>
               <span>Note:</span>
               <span>A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here</span>
             </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jacob</td>
         <td>Thornton</td>
         <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Larry</td>
         <td>the Bird</td>
         <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

since you don't want to use extra tr you may can use this method using css

```css
.tr-holder>td {
  padding-bottom: 35px !important;
}
.full-width {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 9px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr-holder"> <!-- class added -->
      <td>Mark
        <div>Age: 18</div>
        <div>Income: 85</div>
        <div class="full-width"> <!-- class added -->
          <span>Note:</span>
          <span>A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this way. Is it possible to solve this task without additional `tr` tag? I use angular2 and datatables.net for tables, so I can't use additional `tr` for some reason

Comment: i found one solution using css but it will not look good when div element have multiple lines 
https://jsfiddle.net/u0t6bwf5/

Comment: It looks good. I am going to cut if text TOO big. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

specify the **width** of your table.

add this css properties to your style sheet.it will work fine

```
 table
    {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

I'm added the snippet below.

```css
table
{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Mark
            <div>Age: 18</div>
            <div>Income: 85</div>
             <div>
               <span>Note:</span>
               <span>A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here</span>
             </div>
        </td>
         <td>Otto</td>
         <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jacob</td>
         <td>Thornton</td>
         <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Larry</td>
         <td>the Bird</td>
         <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

or you can apply style to your **td div**,as

> td div { width: 100px; overflow: hidden; }

```css
td div { width: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Mark
            <div>Age: 18</div>
            <div>Income: 85</div>
             <div>
               <span>Note:</span>
               <span>A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here</span>
             </div>
        </td>
         <td>Otto</td>
         <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jacob</td>
         <td>Thornton</td>
         <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Larry</td>
         <td>the Bird</td>
         <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I think you didnt understand the problem. Look at Nandhu answer, but I don't want to use separate `tr`.

Comment: @Ron.Basco explained

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an inline CSS

```
<td style="max-width:50px;">Mark
    <div>Age: 18</div>
    <div>Income: 85</div>
    <div>
      <span>Note:</span>
     <span>A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here, A big text here</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: This looks like in [dream hunter’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41216798/4642212). The long line of text should span over multiple columns like in the picture provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like bootstrap or foundations to simulate a table structure