# How to make a table with different sizes of rows and columns in html

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

[html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYHXa.png)

I can make the top two rows using my code but I can't make the third column

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    table, th, td {border: 1px solid black border-collapse: collapse}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr style="height: 30px">
      <th style="width:10%"></th>
      <th style="width: 12%"></th>
      <th style="width: 13%"></th>
      <th style="width: 10%"></th>
      <th style="width: 20%"></th>
      <th style="width: 25%"></th>
      <th style="width: 20%"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 30px">
      <td style="width: 10%"></td>
      <td style="width: 12%"></td>
      <td style="width: 13%"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%"></td>
      <td style="width: 20%"></td>
      <td style="width: 25%"></td>
      <td style="width: 20%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 120px">
      <td style="width:10%"></td>
      <td style="width:25%"></td>
      <td style="width:65%"></td>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code for html. Can anyone tell me please what am I doing wrong? I can't make the third row in the table, while the code works fine up to the 2nd row.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't make the third row?" do you mean column? Maybe unrelated, but you need to add a semicolon after black: table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse}

Comment: Solution can also be found here: [Content of cell should take all row without changing columns width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41216764/2943403) and [Splitting a table cell into two columns in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19115560/2943403) probably tens more places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting widths manually, you need to make sure to follow your table structure. That is 7 columns. Your last row has only 3 columns, so you need to span last column across 5. Change the last one to:

```
<td style="width:65%" colspan="5"></td>
```

Also you might investigate to set columns widths with colgroup/col tags (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp), which will allow you to set styles for all columns without repeating on each row.

Comment: Please flag to close duplicate questions (questions where the solution can already be found on Stack Overflow) instead of answering. This allows the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) can do its important work.  You can be confident that a new question is a duplicate in 2022 if it is asking a basic programming question. Stack Overflow has MILLIONS of pages of programming advice, so it is increasingly and incredibly difficult to asking a clear, unique, minimal, on-topic question.

Comment: @mickmackusa I would need rep. of 3000 to flag duplicates.

Comment: At just 15 rep, you can flag duplicates.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts